# Check value of subarray?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple problem with following code:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('aims_small.html');

$pattern_2 = '/<DIV STYLE=".*?top:(144px|[1-5][0-9][0-9]px).*?left:(7[6-9]px|8[0-4]px).*?width:(52px|[5-8][0-9]px).*?>(.*?)<\/DIV>/';


        $tag = "pattern_2";

        preg_match_all($$tag,$data,$matches);

        $var = $matches[0][2];

        echo 'show content of $var'.$var;

        var_dump($var);

        if($var == "OFF")
        {
        echo "true";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "false";
        }   

?>
```

$matches[0][2] is a subarray created by preg_match_all.
Here is ms array $matches

```
Array 
(   
[0] => Array ( [0] => Oct02 [1] => Wed   [2] => OFF) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 110px [1] => 124px [2] => 144px ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => 76px  [1] => 82px  [2] => 84px ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => 88px  [1] => 52px  [2] => 52px ) 
[4] => Array ( [0] => Oct02 [1] => Wed   [2] => OFF ) 
)
```

Unfortunately every output is false regardless if var is OFF or not.

Edited now with var dump
--> output:

***show content of $var
OFF
string(66) "
OFF
" false***

Both values are OFF but readout is false

Comment: Is there any space? make it `$var = trim($matches[0][2]);`

Comment: A better question: what does `var_dump($var);` output?

Comment: Can you show a var_dump of your $matches ?

Comment: Trim doesn't work and var_dump gives the following output -> See above

Comment: Theox, here you can find var_dump of $matches [link](http://pklingeberg.de/php/test.php)

Comment: $var is array, you cannot compare it with string.